# Using xy-diagram to create an asymmetrical triangle

Tags: diagrams, arrows, xy-pic, commutative-diagrams

I would like to create an asymmetrical triangle like in this picture

[image: picture of diagram]:

Unfortunately so far it only works when I add another label in the top left corner like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry, amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage[matrix,arrow]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{xy}
  \xymatrix{
      B &                          A \ar[d]_p\\
      Y \ar[r]^f \ar[ur]^f            &   X  
  }
\end{xy}
\]
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Just remove the `B` in the top left but leave the `&`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the diagram with `xy`. Note that I loaded `cmtip` which makes proper arrowheads. You are permitted to have empty cells, so simply remove the `B` from the top left entry (but leave the `&`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[matrix,arrow,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}
\[
  \xymatrix{
       & E \ar[d]^{\pi}\\
      X\times I \ar[r]_f \ar[ur]^{\tilde{f}} & B  
  }
\]
\end{document}
```

For comparison, here is the same diagram with `tikz-cd`, which has somewhat improved spacing. There are plenty of die-hard `xy` fans out there, but you might consider switching over to `tikz-cd`, which in general has more flexibility, improved layout and easier syntax.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
& E \arrow[d,"\pi"]\\
X\times I \arrow[r,"f"']\arrow[ur,"\tilde{f}"]& B
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `xy` environment can/should be removed.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. Missed it when I copied OP's code. Fixed now.